# Is there a way to colour meta objects without turning them into meshes?

Tags: meta-objects

Reason being I want to animate them as blobs - once they’re meshed they lose their blobbine nature. I'm interested in creating [this](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi1.wp.com%2Fwww.eyedesyn.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2018%2F12%2Fooze_txt_reveal.gif%3Fzoom%3D2.625%26fit%3D720%252C405%26ssl%3D1&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.eyedesyn.com%2Fblog%2F&docid=FeoxUrMS7fF7WM&tbnid=-tLvVH9amgrx1M%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiK5Om77tnhAhXEfSsKHRgyA48QMwh8KC8wLw..i&w=665&h=374&bih=803&biw=1707&q=make%20blobby%20texture%20youtube&ved=0ahUKEwiK5Om77tnhAhXEfSsKHRgyA48QMwh8KC8wLw&iact=mrc&uact=8) sort of dripping effect, applying it to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa8U1.jpg) character made out of metaobjects - the intention to have certain meta objects running through the rest to create ooze effect. Ideally I'd like it coloured but doesn't work unless they're meshes.

Comment: I'm not an expert but Metaballs can have materials and colors, so what limitations have you met exactly?

Comment: Wow ok I couldnt add colour to metaballs. Figured that wasnt possible unless they were meshes. You just proved me wrong. Not sure what was happening before but gracias!

Comment: You can even give them bumps with the bump node. It would be interesting if you show the result and how you did it, maybe as an answer.